# How to add support to realtime push notifcations in Android?

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to developing using Firebase and developing in Andorid, in general. I have an app where users connect with firebase authentication. I want to implement the following behaviour:

Consider user one that fills a form about his friend and submits it. I want to send a push notification to that friend. I tried to find some information but I'm afraid I will start using something that is not correct. As I understand, we should keep that message in out firebase database. But What is the proper way to create that push notification? I don't want the user to connect randomly to the app and then to fetch if there are new messages.

Comment: this push notification is used by backend in node js that will take token for mobile and then will do function so first you will need to make function in node js

Comment: What do you mean? Do I need to use Google functions for that?

Comment: you will need google function to save token and then pass it to api that make by backend then api or server in turn use google function and specific token (every device has its own token) so api that used google function and key for project will get token you pass as parameter and then push notification and in your side handle all notification message from firebase and notify user with local notification